# How to create an interactive progress slider for the answers in my questionnaire

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```html
<div class="QuestionBody">   
<table role="presentation" class="ChoiceStructure" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"> 
  <tbody> <tr>   
    <td width="20%" class="LabelContatiner ">  
      <span class="LabelWrapper">  
        <label for="QR~QID9~1" class="SingleAnswer" data-runtime-class-q-checked="runtime.Choices.1.Selected" style="padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 20px;">  
          <span>0-5</span>
        </label>
      </span> 
      <label for="QR~QID9~1" class="q-radio" data-runtime-class-q-checked="runtime.Choices.1.Selected"></label> 
    </td>   
    <td width="20%" class="LabelContatiner alt">  
      <span class="LabelWrapper">  
        <label for="QR~QID9~2" class="SingleAnswer" data-runtime-class-q-checked="runtime.Choices.2.Selected" style="padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 20px;">   
          <span>6-10</span>
        </label>
      </span> 
      <label for="QR~QID9~2" class="q-radio" data-runtime-class-q-checked="runtime.Choices.2.Selected"></label> 
    </td>   
    <td width="20%" class="LabelContatiner "> 
      <span class="LabelWrapper">  
        <label for="QR~QID9~3" class="SingleAnswer" data-runtime-class-q-checked="runtime.Choices.3.Selected" style="padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 20px;">   
          <span>11-15</span>
        </label>
      </span> 
      <label for="QR~QID9~3" class="q-radio" data-runtime-class-q-checked="runtime.Choices.3.Selected"></label> 
    </td>   
    <td width="20%" class="LabelContatiner alt">  
      <span class="LabelWrapper">  
        <label for="QR~QID9~4" class="SingleAnswer" data-runtime-class-q-checked="runtime.Choices.4.Selected" style="padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 20px;">   
          <span>16-20</span>
        </label>
      </span> 
      <label for="QR~QID9~4" class="q-radio" data-runtime-class-q-checked="runtime.Choices.4.Selected"></label> </td>   <td width="20%" class="LabelContatiner ">  
    <span class="LabelWrapper">  
      <label for="QR~QID9~5" class="SingleAnswer" data-runtime-class-q-checked="runtime.Choices.5.Selected" style="padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 20px;">   
        <span>20+</span>
      </label>
    </span> 
    <label for="QR~QID9~5" class="q-radio" data-runtime-class-q-checked="runtime.Choices.5.Selected"></label> 
    </td>  
    </tr> 
    <tr>   
      <td style="width: 20%;" class="ControlContainer "> 
        <input choiceid="1" class="radio QR-QID9-1" type="radio" name="QR~QID9" id="QR~QID9~1" value="1" data-runtime-checked="runtime.Selected"> 
      </td>   
      <td style="width: 20%;" class="ControlContainer alt"> 
        <input choiceid="2" class="radio QR-QID9-2" type="radio" name="QR~QID9" id="QR~QID9~2" value="2" data-runtime-checked="runtime.Selected"> 
      </td>   
      <td style="width: 20%;" class="ControlContainer "> 
        <input choiceid="3" class="radio QR-QID9-3" type="radio" name="QR~QID9" id="QR~QID9~3" value="3" data-runtime-checked="runtime.Selected"> 
      </td>   
      <td style="width: 20%;" class="ControlContainer alt"> 
        <input choiceid="4" class="radio QR-QID9-4" type="radio" name="QR~QID9" id="QR~QID9~4" value="4" data-runtime-checked="runtime.Selected"> 
      </td>   
      <td style="width: 20%;" class="ControlContainer "> 
        <input choiceid="5" class="radio QR-QID9-5" type="radio" name="QR~QID9" id="QR~QID9~5" value="5" data-runtime-checked="runtime.Selected"> 
      </td>  
    </tr> 
  </tbody>
  </table> 
</div>
```

Being a beginner to programming, I'm trying to make my questionnaire [Copie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kc8Qc.png) look like this [Prototype](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kspYm.png) . I need a slider that connects all the answer-choices and progresses from left to right according to the answer.Unfortunately, it is not possible to change the HTML code of the website so it must be done either by adding JavaScript or CSS. Any ideas that could help?

Comment: You should at the very least show us any code you've written, to show that you actually tried coding that.

Comment: What do you mean by slider? Are you talking about a sliding navigation?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah this is pretty simple. I'd first tackle the bar which you want to light up with the progress. For this I'd start with a containing div.

```
<div class="Progress"></div>
```

I'd then style this to be the base bar background, looking at your design, something along the lines of:

```
.Progress {
    position: relative;
    width: 600px;
    height: 15px;
    background: #888;
}
```

Then I'd make the process bar, which is the bar which will run in the background leading its way with the dots.

```
<div class="Progress">
    <div class="Progress__glow"></div>
</div>
```

The style for this would be something along the lines of:

```
.Progress__glow {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    background: lightblue;
    width: 0%;
}
```

This will follow the path of the containing div. Changing the width of the element will then change the width of the process. For example.

```
<div class="Progress_glow" style="width: 50%"></div>
```

You can set this with Javascript.

For the dots, I'd do something like this.

```
.Dot {
    position: absolute;
    top: -5px;
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #fff;
}

.Dot--active {
    background: lightblue;
}

.Dot--one {
    left: 0%;
}

.Dot--two {
    left: 25%;
}

.Dot--three {
    left: 50%;
}

.Dot--four {
    left: 75%;
}

.Dot--five {
    left: 100%;
}
```

You can then along with setting the % width of the glow set the active state on which dots have been passed with Javascript.

An example of the CSS working: http://codepen.io/JosephSmith127/pen/KVpxoz

Obviously you can see some tweaks are needed. But this should give you a great start!

Comment: Many thanks for the answer. That is exactly what I'm looking for, in terms of style, but the problem is that I cannot add HTML to the website. It must be done either with JavaScript or with CSS.  @Fausto NA sorry for being so obscure, it's the first time that I post a question here. I would like to share some code with you, but I still don't know how.

Answer (score 1):

I've modified the codepen.io example from JosephSmith to include jquery events when you click on the dots to move the glowline to the clicked on dot: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GZNGVR

HTML HEAD:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="Progress">
      <span id="dotOne" class="Dot Dot--one Dot--active"></span>
      <span id="dotTwo" class="Dot Dot--two"></span>
      <span id="dotThree" class="Dot Dot--three"></span>
      <span id="dotFour" class="Dot Dot--four"></span>
      <span id="dotFive" class="Dot Dot--five"></span>
      <div class="Progress__glow" style="width: 0%;"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* You don't need this bit */
.container {
  margin: 50px;
}

.Progress {
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 99em;
  width: 600px;
  height: 15px;
  background: #888;
}

.Progress__glow {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  background: lightblue;
  width: 0%;
}

.Dot {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  top: -5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #ccc;
  z-index: 2;
}

.Dot--active {
  background: lightblue;
}

.Dot--one { left: 0%; }
.Dot--two { left: 25%; }
.Dot--three { left: 50%; }
.Dot--four { left: 75%; }
.Dot--five { left: 98%; }
```

JS:

```
$('#dotOne').click(function() {
  $('.Progress__glow').css('width', '0%');
  $('#dotOne').addClass('Dot--active');
  $('#dotTwo').removeClass('Dot--active');
  $('#dotThree').removeClass('Dot--active');
  $('#dotFour').removeClass('Dot--active');
  $('#dotFive').removeClass('Dot--active');
});
$('#dotTwo').click(function() {
  $('.Progress__glow').css('width', '26%');
  $('#dotOne').addClass('Dot--active');
  $('#dotTwo').addClass('Dot--active');
  $('#dotThree').removeClass('Dot--active');
  $('#dotFour').removeClass('Dot--active');
  $('#dotFive').removeClass('Dot--active');
});
$('#dotThree').click(function() {
  $('.Progress__glow').css('width', '51%');
  $('#dotOne').addClass('Dot--active');
  $('#dotTwo').addClass('Dot--active');
  $('#dotThree').addClass('Dot--active');
  $('#dotFour').removeClass('Dot--active');
  $('#dotFive').removeClass('Dot--active');
});
$('#dotFour').click(function() {
  $('.Progress__glow').css('width', '76%');
  $('#dotOne').addClass('Dot--active');
  $('#dotTwo').addClass('Dot--active');
  $('#dotThree').addClass('Dot--active');
  $('#dotFour').addClass('Dot--active');
  $('#dotFive').removeClass('Dot--active');
});
$('#dotFive').click(function() {
  $('.Progress__glow').css('width', '101%');
  $('#dotOne').addClass('Dot--active');
  $('#dotTwo').addClass('Dot--active');
  $('#dotThree').addClass('Dot--active');
  $('#dotFour').addClass('Dot--active');
  $('#dotFive').addClass('Dot--active');
});
```